# Разбитие массива на более мелкие

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

Есть массив с объектами

```
NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"1", @"4", @"8", @"2",
                   @"2", @"1", @"6", @"1", @"4", nil];
```

Задача в следующем, разбить это массив на более мелкие массивы с повторяющимися элементами;

Пример:

```
NSArray * array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"1", @"1", @"1", nil];
NSArray * array2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2", @"2", @"2",  nil];
NSArray * array3 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"4", @"4", nil];
NSArray * array4 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"6", nil];
NSArray * array5 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"8", nil];
```

p/s Использовал числа только для примера, на деле сравниваются объекты, и задача одинаковые объекты положить в отдельный массив.

Реализовал через дикшенери

```
    NSString * stringKey = [dictPrice objectForKey:@"product_id"];
if ([[[SingleTone sharedManager] dictBouquets] objectForKey:stringKey]) {
    NSMutableArray * array = [[[SingleTone sharedManager] dictBouquets] objectForKey:stringKey];
    [array addObject:dictPrice];

} else {
    NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:dictPrice];
    [[[SingleTone sharedManager] dictBouquets] setValue:array forKey:stringKey];
}
```

А вот с массивом не выходит...надо как-то сравнивать объекты массива не в цикле а в условии.

Comment: что уже пробовали, что не получилось?

Comment: если объекты одинаковые, то можете создать словарь, где ключом является объект, а значением сколько раз этот объект уже встретился. и потом сконвертировать в массив массивов, просто откопировав объект сколько надо раз

Comment: Объекты это дикшенери приходящий с сервера, ключи не будут повторяться ((

Comment: так они одинаковые, или не будут повторяться?

Comment: Они могут повторятся, например интернет магазин, клиент может загрузить любой товар, при покупке нужно выставлять количество товара, для этого надо отсортировать эти товары.

Comment: все еще не очень понятно

Comment: и какая структура должна получиться на выходе? массив массивов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы найти повторяющиеся элементы можно воспользоваться `NSCountedSet` в любом случае придется пробежаться по массиву (т.е в цикле).
Это не настолько уж дорогостоящая операция будет иметь асимптотику O(n) - за линейное время. Если объектов не много.

```
NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array];

for (id item in set) {

    NSLog(@"Name = %@, Count = %@", item, @([set countForObject:item]));
}
```

Но судя по комментариям к Вашему вопросу, Вам нужно просто получить массив не повторяющихся элементов.

Это можно сделать несколькими способами:

```
// на выходе не отсортированный массив
NSArray *uniqueArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:array] allObjects];

// отсортированный массив
NSArray *uniqueArray2 = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:array] array];

// не отсортированный массив
NSArray *uniqueArray3 = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.self"];
```

Если у Вас задача знать какое количество товара (одинакового) приходит с сервера, то примеры выше помогут. А вообще, чтоб добиться лучшей производительности, необходимо перекинуть эту заботу на сервер. Он должен возвращать товар и его количество.

п.с Используйте литералы при объявлении массива: `NSArray *array = @[@"1", @"2",...];`

Comment: Спасибо попробую !